# When to use factor and ordinal factor?

Tags: r, regression, categorical-data, ordinal-data

When modeling a regression (glm.nb) one of my predictors is the number of sides of a road that has forest next to the road. This means my predictor can take one of three values. 0 = no forest on either side of the road, 1= forest on one side of the road, 2= forest on both sides of the road.

I am a bit confused if this predictor should be a factor, ordinal factor och just numerical. Depending on what I use this predictor varies between being significant or non-significant in my model. So it feels important to choose the right one.

I am leaning towards making it a ordinal factor based on what I have read online, but then I get these "forest.L" and "forest.Q" in my regression model summary, and I can't figure out how to interpret them.

Thanks!

Comment: If the side of the road is important, as in right or left, you may want to split this into two binary variables for left and right side forest presence.

Comment: Thanks for the input, although the side of the road does not matter in my study, just the presence/absence of forest on both sides of the road.

Comment: Almost all software will treat the predictor as unordered anyway.  The exception is the R `brms` package which handles ordered predictors in an elegant Bayesian way.

Comment: @FrankHarrell Maybe I misunderstood your comment. But I get different results in my Glm model depending on if forest is a factor or an ordered factor. If I format my predictor **forest <- as.factor(forest)** I get _forest1_ and _forest2_ in my model summary.  If I format using **Forest <- factor(Forest , order = TRUE, levels = c("0", "1", "2"))** I get _Forest.L_ and _forest.Q_ in my model summary. The estimates and p-values for forest1 and 2 differ from the estimated and p-values of forest.L and .Q.

Comment: Those are contrasts that just restate how the indicator variables are set up.  A 3-level predictor will lead to a 2 degree of freedom test statistic that is identical no matter what coding you using, and predicted values will be identical.  Ordered factors are not really being respected in the sense of strongly using the ordering (like `brms` does) to reduce the effective number of degrees of freedom.  Were your variable to have many more levels you’d really see the inefficiency in these traditional approaches.